# Handle Activities OnClick inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have this layout that Half of the screen is framelayout and the other half is buttons.
The framelayout has a fragment.
And my buttons on the other half has some commands that will change the views of the fragment.
But my problem is, How would I know if the button is clicked which is inside the activity to tell the fragment that button is clicked. 
I cant put the button inside the fragment because the button will be used on other fragment.  If there is only a way.

Comment: have you ever used the getView() method for the fragments? with that you can call the button of that activity inside your fragment

Comment: I will not set the onclick inside the fragment, I want to know if the user click the button inside the fragment

Comment: well you have to create another interface inside the class. to map the onclick function of that button then call that interface method in the activity class

Comment: as mention by Matias

Comment: you can use EventBus library witch support complex communicating model [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiW3v_Pp7nPAhWFtxoKHUZZDC8QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgreenrobot%2FEventBus&usg=AFQjCNGBxF8DNq2PqHA0ZdY9aZOuT9Z_Lw&bvm=bv.134495766,d.d2s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is using interfaces. Define an interface inside your fragment, and let the activity implement that interface.

Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I Tried the link, It worked if I am doing something inside the fragment to send it to the activity. What i want is the other way around,

Comment: I want my activity to say for example that the button is clicked to my fragment.

Comment: Okay, so i have to set onAttachFragment inside activity and follow the rest of the given link. Thank you so much! This worked.